# Getting Error running psql Command for PostgreSQL

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

I have installed the Postgres on my windows 10 PC and I set the environment variable also after when I run psql command it shows following error:
could not connect to server:

> Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

I have checked the port no service is running on 5433 and also tried changing it but getting the same error.I also tried installing Postgres outside Program File (thought maybe it's permission related issue) but still problem persist.I installed Postgres 13

Comment: From an admin console execute `netstat -qb` to see if which port *postgres.exe* listens on.